# write xsi:type using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a way to add the string "xsi:type="SomeType" using XmlWriter class ?

My Element should look like this:

```
<Event xsi:type="SomeEvent" filename="c:\myFile.txt" ilepresence="Present">
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: My apologies, C#.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way to add an attribute "xsi:type" to an Element using XmlWriter.  I ended up using XmlDocument instead and was able to achieve my goal.

This was my code for achieving the same:

```
XmlElement items = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Items");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(items);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://myCompany.com/v1");
```

Then later in the code, I did this:

```
XmlAttribute xsiType = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xsiType.Value = "MyAttributeValue";
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write the start of the element, you can use WriteAttributeString() to add an attribute to it.  For example:

```
string xsins = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

// Make sure you add this namespace to the root element...
writer.WriteAttributeString(localName: "xsi", ns: xmlns,
    value: xsins);

// Now you can reference that namespace in any child element
writer.WriteStartElement("Event");
writer.WriteAttributeString("type", xsins, "xsd:SomeEvent");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: When I'm trying to use "xsi:type" as identifier, it tells me that ":" it not allowed. Any solution for this?

Comment: @duesterdust, you shouldn't need to put the colon (`:`) in your code.  Check out the second to last line of my sample code, above; `WriteAttributeString()` will handle the colon for you.